# Checking login username and password

Tags: php, ajax, authentication

I am trying to verify the user's information against my database without leaving the page, and only if the information is correct should it leave the page and route the user to the user portal. The PHP works fine, it checks the information, and if correct routes the user to the portal, and if false it routes to an empty page.

What I'm trying to do is to intercept the submit, verify it against the database, output an error message if false, and route the user if correct.

I think the error I'm facing is how to get the PHP to somehow "signal" to the jQuery that it's false

I've created a submit handler, that stops the form from submitting, then serializes it and sends it to checkLogin.php, but I get no results after that.

I haven't sent the user anywhere if the info is correct, so it's expected that nothing would happen if the username and password are correct

THIS IS checkLogin.php
- DB is replaced with the actual database that connects, I'm not hosting on localhost, so the info is private

```
<?php

    $link = mysqli_connect('DB', 'DB', 'DB', 'DB'); //Database Connection

    if (!$link) { 
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
    }

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['username']); //Retrieving the username 
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['password']); //Retrieving the password

    $user_sql = "SELECT username FROM login WHERE username = '$username'"; //Setting the SQL query
    $user_check = mysqli_query($link, $user_sql); //Putting the result of the query (^) into a variable

    if ($user_check) {
        $test = "THIS WAS A SUCCESS";
    } else {
        $test = "THIS WAS A FAILURE";
    }
?>
```

This is the function from login.js - the function is called after the user clicks submit

```
function checkLogin() {

    $("#login_form").submit(function(event) { //Submit Handler

        var post = $.post("checkLogin.php", $form.serialize()); 

        post.done(function() { //When the function is successfully submitted

        }); 

        //$("#login_form").submit(); //Submit the form (blocked for now)    
    }); 
}
```

login.html - The form

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" name="login_form" id="login_form">

                    <div class="loginTitle">Client Login</div>

                    <div class="loginLabel">Username: <span id="userError"><?php echo $test ?></span></div>
                    <input type="text" name="username" class="loginBox" id="userName">

                    <div class="loginLabel">Password: <span id="passError"></span></div>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="loginBox" id="passWord">

                    <br>

                    <input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe" value="rememberMe" id="remMe">Remember me for next time

                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" id="submit">

                </form>
```

login.html - at the top

```
<?php
    include ("checkLogin.php");
?>
```

Expected: It should say "This was a failure" next to the form label when I enter the wrong username

Actual: Nothing

Comment: Your `post.done(function() { });` is incomplete. You don't know how to complete it? Have you checked that the function inside is actually called? (remember, we cannot run your code) Ah, you also don't seem to block the submit in your javascript.

Comment: `mysql_error` function does not exist, you are looking for [`mysqli_connect_error`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php)